# How to print the current code, which executes a program in runtime?

Tags: c#, runtime, clr, metadata, disassembly

I have an application ( web-service ).

I want to print some function's hints/description of it, but NOT from the DB, textfile or other prepared context, BUT from the current web-service, which is running in live mode.

I want just to copy the source code of it and then post it via web to the client for showing the real function definiton in realtime/runtime. It's important to make him always available to look the fresh changes and for NOT depending on perviously required prepared context for hints.

Are there any suggestions?

I know, that CLR metadata is easy to disassemble and may there is a way to do it for my aim, what do you think?

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve here? Why would showing the source code help the end user?

Comment: Just a suggestion to get you on the right path; if it were me, at first, I'd keep the code block in database just fine, and automate compiling that code block into a library. Then that library becomes a plugin for the main webservice that you can reference in a late-binding manner, and you can execute code blocks from it. The webservice would be checking for new libraries on demand and plug them in, and make them available for the frontend to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

You can not access the *code* of the function in execution, but I doubt that you actually need a *code* of the function itself, instead you need a *definition* of the function.

For this you can use [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) class, that provides information about `StackTrace` at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

This future you can be implemented only by embedding your classes and methods with attributes after the assembly has been built only. The logic is:

1. Build you assembly
2. On post-build execute utility which:

   1. gets as parameters you assembly and path to source code
   2. finds methods' and classes' definitions in source code files
   3. using somesthing like PostSharp adds attribute to every method and class of your assembly  (attribute will contain method or class code)
3. at runtime service will find this attribute value and will use it as you need.